# Using Processhtml with Jade in Grunt.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, pug

I would like to change the content of an HTML file for a build, like this:

```
<!-- build:css css/tidy.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<!-- /build -->
```

To generate the HTML file I am using Jade:

```
//
  build:css css/tidy.css
link(href='css/main.css', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')
//
  /build
```

When Jade finishes creating the HTML files, this is the output:

```
<!--build:css css/tidy.css
-->
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--/build
-->
```

The lack of space after the two dashes at the beginning and the line break at the end of each comment, prevent Processhtml to do its job. Is there a way to fix this automatically? Like an option in the task or another grunt plugin? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
// build:css css/tidy.css
```

Or write html directly in jade:

```
<!-- build:css css/tidy.css -->
```